# How to run large amount of blocking/sync I/O operations

Tags: .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a list of around 100k users and I need to perform a sync WCF call for each of them and I need to complete the list as fast as possible. Each WCF call is around 200ms-1s depending the server status. I was thinking of using `Parallel.For` but is there better way?

Comment: Can you create a batch endpoint in the WCF service?

Comment: Why can't you do this asynchronously, why does it *have* to be sync?

Comment: @mtkachenko and Charlieface : I can't modify WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking IO is not awkward to parallelize because it ties up threads, and threads are relatively expensive. Additionally, increasing parallelism can often *degrade* performance if all the work is going to the same backend, as it can increase a lot of overheads at the server and hit bottlenecks.

IMO the real problem here is the size of the unit-of-work, where it sounds like you need to perform an API call per rexord; 1000 batches of (say) 100 records is usually vastly more performance than 100k single operations. If it was me, I'd be looking to refactor this into a batched API. If the underlying service can't be changed, another option is to run an orchestration service *as close to the backend as possible* (same box, ideally), that can at least receive batches and unroll them locally, minimizing latency overheads. Note however that if latency isn't a significant factor in the current issue, this won't help: if the 200ms-1s is simply due to a slow server implementation, then *you probably can't do much to work around that* (except maybe ... invest the time to make it less slow).

A secondary concern here would be async; async can be important (especially server-side), but in this instance it isn't where I'd focus.

Comment: Shouldn't that be on the first line *Blocking IO **is** awkward to parallelize*

Comment: Thank you Marc. The problem is I can neither modify the WCF service to create a batch endpoint nor create an additional orchestration service. I simply have to use this single method, I don't have any other options. My hope with Parallel.For is to maximize the server utilization with multiple parallel requests and again hopefully make it faster than simple using a for loop. This code will run at a time where there are no other applications running on the server so it's mostly ok to tie up as much threads as it can.

Comment: well then, sure, `Parallel.For` I guess - but: "go chunky"; by which I mean - say you have 100k records to process; using `Parallel.For` / `ForEach` on 100 batches of 1000 elements each, *even if all you do is `foreach` over that 1000 and call your WCF service per element* will have *far fewer overheads* than 100,000 operations of 1 element each (so: the "batching" here only applies to how we're executing the parallelism - I understand that you can't change the WCF service itself to be batched)

Comment: @MarcGravell : Do you mean to use something like `Partitioner.Create(0, list.Count, 1000)`?

Comment: @dstr yes, that or something semantically equivalent